# How to cancel an erroneous tag request on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

I was browsing a photo album on Facebook and did some tag request. In hindsight, I noticed that I mistook the last name, so now I have issued a bunch of false tag request. I do not see an obvious way to remove those tag requests.

How do I cancel these photo tag requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the photo and hover the name next to "With..", a tool-tip must appear click on "Remove Tag" to cancel the tag request.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!!!! ...never thought I'd need this feature.